# Most recents files/directory suggested results by TAB completion with zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I would like to get with <kbd>TAB</kbd> suggestion on `zsh` to get the more recent file as first suggestion after a second <kbd>TAB</kbd> pushing.

For the moment, I have with a first <kbd>TAB</kbd> pushing the list of the more recent files : the most recent that is displayed at the bottom. But my issue occurs at the second <kbd>TAB</kbd> pushing : the suggestion done is not the most recent.

I have the following configuration in `~/.zshrc` :

```zsh
alias l='grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -lrt'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# Colorize completions using default `ls` colors.
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
    
# Zsh reverse auto-completion
zmodload zsh/complist
    
# Option
zstyle ':completion:*' add-space false
    
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
    
# Block important
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(python3.9|ls|cd|cp|rm|mv|vim|cat|more|tail|head|n|open|vimdiff|diff):*' file-sort date reverse
    
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
```

Could someone provide a missing option or a workaround to have the most recent file suggested as the first option with a second <kbd>TAB</kbd> press, followed by the remaining files in order of their recency for subsequent <kbd>TAB</kbd> presses?

**UPDATE 1** : I was advised to use `fzf` or `fzf-tab` (I don't know exactly the difference between both) to perform what I have described above. Has anyone already used these tools or plugins to play with <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion and been able to indicate me the appropriate commands in `~/.zshrc` for my wanted result ? Actually, I would prefer a pure `zsh` workaround and avoid using `oh-my-zsh`.

**UPDATE 2**: Here a link that illustrates my issue : I make a first `l`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> then I can see the most recent files and directories at the end of list. Then, if I push a second <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I have not the most recent but the first old files/directories as suggestions.

I would like that the second push of <kbd>TAB</kbd> suggested me the most recent files, not the oldest (as you can see at the end of the animation, I am obliged to do a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to get back to the most recent files/directories).

Comment: It's not clear what your issue here is. If you want the list to be sorted from most recent to least, just remove that `reverse`. If you want tab completion to cycle choices starting with the last one going backward, bind `reverse-menu-complete` to Tab. `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2` makes the choice selection more visual.